# Using multiple commas per sentence to increase the number of concepts that can be mentioned

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis

I have a pretty loaded sentence with numerous commas and I am not sure whether the comma usage is appropriate.

"Pyrene was shown to bind weakly, and one of its derivatives, 1-aminopyrene, more strongly to THRA and THRB, using competitive binding immunoassays."

Can someone please assist?

I have recently adopted this style of writing, using multiple commas per sentence in order to load it with information. I am not English and I may be totally off track!

Comment: I would suggest that you not try to cram it all into one sentence.

Comment: Using competitive binding immunoassays it was shown that pyrene binds weakly to THRA and THRB, and that one of its derivatives, 1-aminopyrene, binds more strongly.

Comment: What Edwin A. says. Or, to keep the parallelism but make it marginally clearer, add even one more comma (and an expanded duplicated parallel): "Pyrene was shown to bind weakly, and one of its derivatives, 1-aminopyrene, to bind more strongly, to THRA and THRB, using competitive binding immunoassays.

Comment: If you ask yourself that question, the sentence probably needs rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

**Edwin Ashworth** has provided the best answer so far this morning:

"Using competitive binding immunoassays it was shown that pyrene binds weakly to THRA and THRB, and that one of its derivatives, 1-aminopyrene, binds more strongly."

I'm assuming, of course, that Mr. Ashworth's re-writing does not change the meaning of what you wanted to say.

Comment: Thank you so much your response! Yes, the proposed sentence maintains the meaning, but makes more sense. Thank you!